# Ionic 2 get back to previous page from where it has been redirected to Login/Signup

Tags: ionic2

I am creating an app in which I want to implement if user tries to go to cart page and if the user is not logged in then redirect the user back to login page and after successful login redirect the user back to the source page from where it has come.But I am unable to do so. 
    Below the piece of code I am trying please let me know how to do this -
     //checking the authentication if user logged in

```
 this.storage.get('authid').then((value) =>{
        this.apitoken = value;
        if(this.apitoken == '' || this.apitoken == undefined || this.apitoken == null){
            let emsg = this.toast.create({
                message:'Please try again',
                duration:2000
            })
            emsg.present();
            this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
            this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(Login); //Redirect to login page if not logged in
        }
        else{
            this.storage.get('deviceid').then((val) =>{
                this.dev_id = val;
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(CartPage); // go to cart page.
            })
        }
    })


 Login page - 
 if(data['code'] != 200){
                let errmsg = this.toast.create({
                    message:data['message'],
                    duration:2000
                });
                errmsg.present();
            }
            else{
                let smsg = this.toast.create({
                    message:data['message'],
                    duration:2000
                });
                smsg.present();
                this.storage.set('authid',data['data'].API_CURRENT_TOKEN);
         //Here I am redirecting to Menu page if dircetly click on loginpage but if it has redirected from any other page to login then it should go back to previous page(which is not happening). 
                this.navCtrl.push(Menu,{
                    userInfo:data['data'],
                    is_multiple: 2
                })
                .then(() => {         
                    const index = this.view.index;
                    this.navCtrl.remove(index);
                });
                // this.navCtrl.setRoot(ChangePassword,{'auth':data['data'].API_CURRENT_TOKEN});
            }
```

Please help me to get out of this situation.My Login page is not a modal.

Thanks,
Dia

Answer (score 0):

Cart Page

```
this.storage.get('authid').then((value) =>{
        this.apitoken = value;
        if(this.apitoken == '' || this.apitoken == undefined || this.apitoken == null){
            let emsg = this.toast.create({
                message:'Please try again',
                duration:2000
            })
            emsg.present();
            this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
            this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage,{previousPage: "CartPage"}, {animate: true, direction: 'forward'}); //Redirect to login page if not logged in and Set Cart page name as previousPage parameter 
        }
        else{
            this.storage.get('deviceid').then((val) =>{
                this.dev_id = val;
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(CartPage); // go to cart page.
            })
        }
    })
```

Loin Page

```
if(data['code'] != 200){
                let errmsg = this.toast.create({
                    message:data['message'],
                    duration:2000
                });
                errmsg.present();
            }
            else{
                let smsg = this.toast.create({
                    message:data['message'],
                    duration:2000
                });
                smsg.present();
                this.storage.set('authid',data['data'].API_CURRENT_TOKEN);
         //Here I am redirecting to Menu page if dircetly click on loginpage but if it has redirected from any other page to login then it should go back to previous page(which is not happening).

                if(navParams.get('previousPage') != "undefined" )
                {
                    this.navCtrl.push(Menu,{
                    userInfo:data['data'],
                    is_multiple: 2
                      })
                    .then(() => {         
                      const index = this.view.index;
                      this.navCtrl.remove(index);
                     });
                }else
                {
                 //Here you get CartPage Name
                   this.navCtrl.push(navParams.get('previousPage'),{
                    userInfo:data['data'],
                    is_multiple: 2
                      });
                 }


                // this.navCtrl.setRoot(ChangePassword,{'auth':data['data'].API_CURRENT_TOKEN});
            }
```

Comment: I have already tried this way but throwing error
Uncaught (in promise): invalid link:CartPage

Comment: `import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';` and then use annotation `@IonicPage({
  name: "CartPage"
})`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
this.navCtrl.push(this.navCtrl.getPrevious().name);
```

to get back to previous page after login.